# How can method overloading be avoided?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I have the following situation:

A constructor takes 6 values.
Some of them have default values, some not.

```
#pseudocode# Foo(int a, int b=2, int c=3, int d=4, int e=5, int f){}
```

And I want to be able to call all possible combinations without having to write always all 6 parameters.

```
#pseudocode# Foo f1 = new Foo(a=1, d=7, f=6);
#pseudocode# Foo f2 = new Foo(a=1, b=9, d=7, f=6);
```

Besides doing this with method overloading (which would be tedious), is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Please note that in C#, optional parameters can only appear behind all required parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx#ae5c52e6-1e45-49e2-af8e-c1bf8e2cee1f

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in C# 4, there are named parameters see [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

which would result in

```
new Foo(a: 1, d: 7, f: 6);
```

Another solution wwould be to define a Constructor with your defaut value ans use Object Initializer to set the values [How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)

```
new Foo()
{
    a = 1,
    d = 7,
    f = 6
};
```

Comment: More precisely, C# 4. The language, not the framework. (comment before edit but I'm leaving it here for context)

Comment: Technically it's a C# 4 feature not a .net 4 feature.

Comment: For those who aren't aware of the point that @BoltClock is trying to make it, that means that if you are compiling in VS2010 you can use the C# 4 compiler but still compile to .NET 3.5 so you can use optional parameters without requiring the client to have .NET 4 as long as the compiling machine does.

Comment: Cool, exactly what I was looking for!

But what if the parameters are not const but something like:
new Foo(a: new Vector(2,3), d: 7); ?

Comment: @Alan: What do you mean by "not const"?

Comment: "Default values must be constants." (from the linked MSDN page.)

Comment: @Alan: the default value yes, but not when you call the function with named parameters with, I tought that's what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

use the following for naming arguments:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo(a: 1, d: 7, f: 6);
Foo f2 = new Foo(a: 1, b: 9, d: 7, f: 6);
```

More information on Named and Optional Arguments avalable here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx#Y515

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer refactoring to a [Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html). Something like:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo (new FooParameters () { B = 7 })
```

And your FooParamaters class can encapsulate the defaults:

```
public class FooParameters
{
     public int A { get; set; }
     public int B { get; set; }


     public FooParameters ()
     {
          A = 1;
          B = 2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1) default parameters are left to right, once you start defaulting parameters you cannot have a non-defaulted after it, so `f` must have a default (in your example)

2) you can use parameter naming to skip over a default parameter:

`var f1 = new Foo(5, 9, e: 9, f: 10);`

This gives a =5, b = 9, c = the default, d = default, e = default, f = 10

Provided you are using C# 4.0 compiler of course...

Comment: Are you sure it only works if you target .net 4? I thought the attribute behind optional parameters is older than that. And C# 4 can target older frameworks.

Comment: It's a C# 4 language feature, it's really just syntactical sugar.

Comment: More specifically the user of the application does not require .NET 4.0 because you can compile to .NET 3.5 with a C# 4.0 compiler and still use optional parameters.

Comment: It's cute that the comments here just mirror everything said in an earlier answer :P

Comment: Indeed!  Has an elegant symmetry.